# Connection Strings in "Choose Your Data Connection Dialog Box" (Entity Data Model Wizard)

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework-4

I deleted an old edmx file and I attempted to add a new one via Add > New Item> Visual C# Templates (data) - ADO.NET Entity Data Model.

[image]

In the wizard, in the "Choose your Data Connection" window, there are some pre-existing connection strings. Where are these values taken from? I searched my solution for the connection strings but there weren't any.

How do I delete these pre-existing connection strings so that they don't show up the next time?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

These connection are not stored in your solution - they are completely unrelated to your solution. They are stored somewhere in Visual Studio. If you open Server Explorer and expand Data Connections node you will see all of them and you will be able to remove those you don't want to use anymore.

Comment: Thank you!  This was so non-obvious